# Register double taps multiple times

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created something that is recognizing double taps on a UIView. The action is sent trough a selector. However, it will only register the double tap once. I want it to run multiple times. I think one way of fixing it is to set the registered taps to 0 again, or using a timer or something. I'll appreciate every answer, thanks.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *DoubleClick = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(DoubleClickRegistered:)];
    DobbelKlikk.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:DobbelKlikk];
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. What do you mean you "created something". What code have you written, exactly?

Comment: I added the relevant part of the code. I gave them some non-english names when i wrote it, just say the word if you need the translation.

Comment: Nothing wrong there, what is the selector method doing.

Comment: It's nothing wrong with the code, but i have to change it in order for it to work the way i wish. Cause that code will only register the double tap once, not if i'm doing multiple double taps.

Comment: No, that code will register it every time. What is the code in your selector method doing.

Comment: The selector method is added.

Comment: I'm not clear on what that code in the selector is doing, but if you add `NSLog(@"Double clicked");` inside of your `DobbelKlikk` method you will see it get logged out every time you double click.

Comment: As a non native English speaker, it saddens me when I see fellow foreigners mix their own native language with English in the code they write. Nothing to do with your question per se, but if you want to tap into the `world` knowledge, you are probably better off sticking to English through and through. Beside, having some of your own defined words in English `isTorchActive` and others in what I assume is German `DobbelKlikk` doesn't look very consistent ...

Comment: If you guys think it would help, i can write an explanation of the code and translate the names i gave them to english. Off topic; It's Norwegian, not German :)

Comment: The translation is done. What i'm doing in the selector is that i'm getting a value defined in an other viewcontroller, trough NSUserDefaults. I had to define it as an NSString and get the BOOL value, because the NSUserDefaults don't like Booleans, from my experience. Anyway, that part is working just fine. When the user double taps on the view, the torch will be turned on, and the background will change. If the user doubletaps again, the torch will turn off and the background will change again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I abstracted this out so that you can see that it will work. The problem is something in your selector it has nothing to do with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(weeee)];
tapRecog.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecog];

- (void)weeee
{
    NSLog(@"Two taps");
    self.wee = !self.wee;

    if (!self.wee) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        NSLog(@"Wee is false");
    } else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSLog(@"Wee is true");
    }
}
```

If you add that to a project (include a `BOOL` property for `wee` and set it in `viewDidLoad`) every time you double tap the background color will change.

With regards to your code I would recommend setting some break points and figuring out what values are set and what they're set to. Somewhere, there is something thats not happening the way you're expecting it to happen. For example if `isTorchActive` is never true, then it'll always switch to white. I don't know where you're setting that, but that is most likely the problem.